# VLC 2.2.5 color problem after update in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vlc

There where some video driver related updates, after which I have this problem with VLC.

Note that, I have a video paused (in VLC) during update process, and after it completed, that video could be played normally. But any later video file I open with VLC looks like this:

[image]

I have tried disabling *Accelerated Video Output (Overlay)* and *Hardware Accelerated Decoding*, but it remained the same.

Totem plays the video fine.

Log from the said day:

```
Start-Date: 2017-01-18  18:03:34
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.189'
Upgrade: dbus-x11:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3), libgles2-mesa:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.74+git1701131830.e1ee01~gd~x, 2.4.74+git1701161830.5856a5~gd~x), libgles1-mesa:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), dbus:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:amd64 (0.2.17.1+16.04.20151117-0ubuntu1, 0.2.17.1+16.04.20151117-0ubuntu1.16.04.1), libxatracker2:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), overlay-scrollbar:amd64 (0.2.17.1+16.04.20151117-0ubuntu1, 0.2.17.1+16.04.20151117-0ubuntu1.16.04.1), initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 (0.122ubuntu8.7, 0.122ubuntu8.8), libgbm1:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), libwayland-client0:amd64 (1.9.0-1, 1.11.0-2~gd~x), apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.74+git1701131830.e1ee01~gd~x, 2.4.74+git1701161830.5856a5~gd~x), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.74+git1701131830.e1ee01~gd~x, 2.4.74+git1701161830.5856a5~gd~x), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.74+git1701131830.e1ee01~gd~x, 2.4.74+git1701161830.5856a5~gd~x), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.74+git1701131830.e1ee01~gd~x, 2.4.74+git1701161830.5856a5~gd~x), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (17.0~git1701130730.64272d~gd~x, 17.0~git1701180730.aa291c~gd~x), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.4, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5), initramfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.122ubuntu8.7, 0.122ubuntu8.8), initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.122ubuntu8.7, 0.122ubuntu8.8), libwayland-server0:amd64 (1.9.0-1, 1.11.0-2~gd~x), libwayland-cursor0:amd64 (1.9.0-1, 1.11.0-2~gd~x)
End-Date: 2017-01-18  18:06:19
```

EDIT: There had been a couple more updates, yesterday and today, and after the later one, VLC works normally again.

Comment: What updates are you talking about? Were they installed through Apt? If so, could you please [edit] your question to include the relevant section(s) of `/var/log/apt/history.log`? Thanks.

Comment: I don't remmber the exact updates. There was something related to the VDPAU and similar. I have updated the system via the Ubuntu system updater (graphical interface). I will add that log when I get back from work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you have a rough idea when the issue started occurring and compare that to the time stamps of the Apt history we'll be able to see which package changes occurred at the time.

Comment: This is the log from that day: (added in original question).

Comment: OK, after the latest updates, VLC works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried purging the vlc package and reinstalling it, with:

```
sudo apt remove --purge vlc -y && sudo apt install vlc -y
```

Comment: No. I will try when I get back from work.

Comment: I have tried it, and no change.

Comment: Never mind, after the last update, VLC works again.

Comment: For future use, I recommend `sudo apt --purge --reinstall install vlc` instead  of separate `apt` invocations to remove and install the package. That one command will purge and reinstall the package in one command,  and will download the package (if necessary) first before it performs any actions.